# adding jenkins user to docker group usermod vs gpasswd

Tags: unix, jenkins, docker

For running docker command in jenkins , I need to add jenkins user to docker group.

Below are the 2 ways I found through googling but I'm not clear if they will do same thing or has got any differences at all ?

**sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins**

**sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker**

Please clarify

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: This question has a duplicate on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/688685/usermod-ag-vs-gpasswd-a-as-a-best-practice

Comment: Agree this is answered in link provided by @DaveBacher. Please close this question as duplicate